# CSS with Kevin Roth's RTE

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a CSS with Kevin Roth's free [Cross-Browser Rich Text Editor](http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/).

The docs say:

```
//Usage: initRTE(imagesPath, includesPath, cssFile, genXHTML, encHTML)
initRTE("./images/", "./", "", true);
```

However, when I include my CSS like this it seems to be completely ignored:

```
initRTE("./images/", "./", "style.css", true);
```

Does anyone have a real working CSS file with the RTE that I could use to experiment with?

Comment: @Maciej, please try to fix all problems in a question when editing, e.g. links and signatures.  Thanks.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Point taken. Will try to in the future. Thanks.